# выравнивание :after/:before(content) вертикально по-центру

Tags: html, css

Нужно выровнять content у :after вертикально по-центру, чтобы "-" было на уровне кругов.
[Ссылка](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=e037d107fae00dd0dce755b27df64a34) на желаемый результат

https://jsfiddle.net/rojfnekx/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span>purple</span>
    <div></div>
    <span>#967cb9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>green</span>
    <div></div>
    <span>#9fba7c</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>dark gray</span>
    <div></div>
    <span>#515351</span>
  </div>
</div>

.container{
}
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.box:after{
  content: "-";
}
.box div{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: А есть у вас картинка того как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: собственно ссылка [тык](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=e037d107fae00dd0dce755b27df64a34)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это если вам нужно по центру круга

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span>purple</span>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <span>#967cb9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>green</span>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <span>#9fba7c</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>dark gray</span>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <span>#515351</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант №1

```
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle:after{
  content: "-";
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px
}
.circle{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Вариант №2

```
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle:after{
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно через псевдоелемент :after то для `.box:after` задайте `color: white;` чтобы было видно тире, и

```
position: relative;
  top: -25px; //меняем расположение элемента по вертикали
  left: -30px;//меняем расположение элемента по горизонтали
```

Или так:

```css
.container{
}
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.box .purple {
  width:30px;
  height:25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: #967cb9;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  }

.box div{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span>purple</span>
    <div class="purple">-</div>
    <span>#967cb9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>green</span>
    <div></div>
    <span>#9fba7c</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>dark gray</span>
    <div></div>
    <span>#515351</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а возможно ли сделать так, чтобы не пикселями, а всегда находилось на уровне круга?

Comment: если нужно конкретно по центру круга, то это вообще не так делаеться

Comment: нужно, чтобы было на уровне круга, ну центра соответственно, буду благодарен за помощь и подсказку

Answer (score 0):

Вариант №3

```
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.box:after{
  content: "";
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: -15%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Если согласно той картинке что вы дали делаете верстку, то у Вас там не тире и не дефис, а просто линия, да и с ней проще всего в этом случае совладать, и еще нужно добавить это, чтобы последнюю не рисовало )))

```
.box:last-child:after {
   display: none;
}
```

Прошу обратить внимание на **right: -15%;** это вам нужно будет самостоятельно уже подобрать, согласно вашего макета

Comment: собственно ссылка на изображение  [тык-тык](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=e037d107fae00dd0dce755b27df64a34)

Comment: Пользуйтесь, вариант №3 это то что Вам нужно )))

Comment: отличная идея, единственная трабла, что right не задаст одинакового отступа от всех эллементов

Comment: но я премного благодарен вам, спасибо:)

Comment: при например таком раскладе https://jsfiddle.net/rojfnekx/3/

Comment: Вообще согласно Вашей картинке, то там одинаковая ширина у всех блоков с кружочками, и если уж она разная, то про псевдо классы можете забыть в этой ситуации, только дорисовка нового контейнера (элемента), между контейнерами (элементами) с кружочками, который будет содержать линию.

Comment: наверное вы правы, псевдоклассы как раз и будут пороть всю картинку, потому что по сути каждый див будет разной ширины из-за текста